# Add values from count that have come from a UNION

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to add together the values_occurrence for the id's that match. For example ID number 1 has 3 and another record shows ID number 1 having 4. I want to ADD 3 + 4 based on the ID matching.

I am trying to see which ID has the most entries in each table and then add them together.

```
ID  value_occurrence
--------------------
1    3
1    4
```

so far this is what I have.

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) AS value_occurrence 
FROM     TABLE1
GROUP BY ID
UNION 
SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) AS value_occurrence 
FROM     TABLE2
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `union` is almost surely wrong; it should be `union all`. `union` eliminates duplicates, so if for an ID you have the same count in both tables, you will get only one of the counts instead of both. Then: You are contradicting yourself. Do you want to know which ID has the most entries in EACH TABLE or in the combination of both tables together? Probably added together. And then, what should be the result if there is more than one ID with the maximum count (let's say, if the maximum is 12, but there are three different ID's each with a count of 12)? What is the exact output you need?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I am trying to see which ID has the most entries in each table and then add them together."  What if different ids have the most entries in each of the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `union all` and then aggregate:

```
select id, count(*) as total_cnt, sum(t1) as t1_cnt, sum(t2) as t2_cnt
from ((select id, 1 as t1, 0 as t2 from table1) union all
      (select id, 0, 1 from table2)
     ) t
group by id
order by id;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to show "which ID has the most entries" (from the OP's requirement).

Comment: @mathguy . . . To be honest, I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Me neither. That is why I started with a question back to the OP, asking for clarification - not with a solution to a problem I don't even understand what it means.